# Incorrect answer given by RSolve

Tags: bugs, difference-equations

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

---

*Also posted in [Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/896073).*

I tried to solve the following nonlinear recurrence relation using `RSolve`.

```
y[n+1] = y[n] - a - b Sqrt[y[n]]
```

But the solution given by `RSolve` does not satisfy the relation.

Have I missed anything regarding RSolve or is this a bug in Mathematica?

Code is given below.

```
RSolve[y[n + 1] ==  y[n] - a - b Sqrt[y[n]], y, n]

FullSimplify[y[n + 1] == y[n] - a - b Sqrt[y[n]] /. %]
```

[image: Sample Output]

Comment: even making it more specific, we get a clearly wrong result, eg  : `RSolve[{y[n + 1] == y[n] + 1 + Sqrt[y[n]], y[0] == 1}, y, n]`   (I'm pretty sure there is not a closed form solution, but obviously we shouldn't get an incorrect solution)

Comment: When you [crosspost at Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/896073), please have the courtesy to mention that you posted at SE, and vice versa.

Comment: @J.M., I apologise for my mistake. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Considering Devendra's answer, can anybody with access to earlier versions add the customary header?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug in RSolve.

The problem appears to be caused by a missing check while applying a transformation to solve this example, which should have returned unevaluated with the available methods.

Sorry for the confusion caused by the incorrect answer.