# Symbolic recursion

Tags: recursion

I have the two recursive relations:

```
(n + 1) (n + 2) (n + 3) (n + 4) Subscript[x, n + 4] - 2*k^2 (n + 1) (n + 2) Subscript[x, n + 2] + k^4 Subscript[x, n] - k*R*Subscript[y, n]=0;
(n + 1) (n + 2) Subscript[y, n + 2] - k^2 Subscript[y, n] + Subscript[x, n]=0;
```

with

```
Subscript[x, 0]=0,Subscript[x, 1]=1, Subscript[x, 2]=0; Subscript[x, 3]=a1/6; Subscript[y, 0]=0;Subscript[y, 1]=a2.
```

I would like to find `Subscript[x, N]` and `Subscript[y, N]` where N=3,...,20. What I have done so far is to manually substitute for each N. Can anyone please tell me how can I do this in an efficient manner using Mathematica?

I have come across an issue in the same problem which I have commented below.

Comment: Please look into [`RSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html) and examples therein. Also, try avoiding `Subscript` because it may cause troubles. Use `x[0]` instead of `Subscript[x, 0]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned, you should not use subscripted variables. Use indexed variables instead.

Then your system can be solved by:

```
Clear["Golbal`*"]
eq = {
  x[0] == 0,
  x[1] == 1,
  x[2] == 0,
  x[3] == a1/6,
  y[0] == 0,
  y[1] == a2,
  
  (n + 1) (n + 2) (n + 3) (n + 4) x[n + 4] - 
    2*k^2 (n + 1) (n + 2) x[n + 2] + k^4 x[n] - k*R*y[n] == 0,
  (n + 1) (n + 2) y[n + 2] - k^2 y[n] + x[n] == 0
  }
res=RSolve[eq, {x[n], y[n]}, n];
```

This results in a long list with DifferenceRoots. To get functions for the results of x and y, you can write:

```
resx[n_] = x[n] /. res ;
resy[n_] = y[n] /. res ;
```

Now we can create a table with x[n] and y[n]:

```
Table[{i, resx[i]}, {i, 3, 20}] // TableForm
```

[image]

The table for resy is rather large, so I only show the beginning:

```
Table[{i, resy[i]}, {i, 3, 20}] // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting an error: ReplaceAll::reps: {RSolve[{x[0]==0,x[1]==1,<<5>>,x[n]-k^2 y[n]+(1+n) (2+n) y[Plus[<<2>>]]==0},{x[n],y[n]},n]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. I use Mathematica version 11

Comment: Obviously "RSolve" did not do its job. I checked the code and it runs on my computer. I have MMA 13.3.0.  Try restarting MMA and copy the code again. If it does not run, it may be a version problem.

Comment: It works perfectly fine on Wolfram Cloud. Definitely its the version problem which is also point out in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121756/incorrect-answer-given-by-rsolve. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I did not know about this bug.

Answer (score 0):

There must be an Equal == and not Set = in the recursion equations

```
   k^4 x_n - 2 k^2 (n + 1) (n + 2) x_ {n + 2} - 
          k R y_n + (n + 1) (n + 2) (n + 3) (n + 4) x_ {n + 4} == 0
```

The higest index must be the variable to be replaced, subtract 4 from all indizes and solve for $x_n$ and make $x_{{n\_}{\_}}$ on the left of rule a Subscript with a PatternObject  for the index

```
     Solve[r /. {n :> n - 4}, Subscript[x, n]][[1]] /. 
         {Subscript[x_,  n] :> Subscript[x, n_], Rule -> RuleDelayed}
```

$$\left\{x_{\text{n$\_$}}:\to \frac{-k^4 x_{n-4}+2 k^2 n^2 x_{n-2}-10 k^2 n x_{n-2}+12 k^2 x_{n-2}+k R y_{n-4}}{(n-3) (n-2) (n-1) n}\right\}$$

and the same for the other rule

```
       Solve[(n + 1) (n + 2) Subscript[y, n + 2] - k^2 Subscript[y, n] +
           Subscript[x, n] == 0 /. 
     {n -> n - 2}, Subscript[y, n]][[1]] /. {Subscript[y_, n] :> Subscript[y, n_], 
       Rule -> RuleDelayed}
```

$$\left\{y_{\text{n$\_$}}:\to \frac{k^2 y_{n-2}-x_{n-2}}{(n-1) n}\right\}$$

In order to avoid zeros in the denominator, define the replacements correctly with lower bound

```
    s1 = {Subscript[x, n_?(# >= 4 &)] :> 
      (-k^4 Subscript[x, -4 + n] +   12 k^2 Subscript[x, -2 + n] - 
         10 k^2 n Subscript[x, -2 + n] + 2 k^2 n^2 Subscript[x, -2 + n] + 
          k R Subscript[y, -4 + n])/((-3 + n) (-2 + n) (-1 + n) n)

    s2 = {Subscript[y, n_?(# >= 2 &)] :> (-Subscript[x, -2 + n] + 
            k^2 Subscript[y, -2 + n])/((-1 + n) n)}

    Table[Subscript[y, k] //. Join[s1, s2], {k, 5, 8}]
```